# Android Getting Extras from Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to use startActivityForResult() to get a String from another activity, but I keep getting a NullPointerException whenever I try to retrieve the String from the Intent.  Here's what I've got:

```
//To set up the Intent:
String in = mEditText.getText().toString(); //medittext is EditText that I want String from
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityLoaderActivity.class); //activity that started this one
i.putExtra("message", in);
setResult(1);
this.finish(); //cause I'm using startActivityForResult()

//To get the String
@Override
protected void onActivityResult( ... , Intent data) {
    String s = data.getStringExtra("message"); //error here
}
```

I know the error is at getStringExtra() through debugging, but I still can't figure out why it's crashing.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try using `setResult(1, i)` and checking in `onActivityResult()` for the resultCode before getting the extra like this

```
if(resultCode == 1)
{
   //get String extra
}
```

Hope it helps